# Angular 6 & rxjs 6 - subscription returns undefined

Tags: sharepoint, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I am using Angular CLI 6.1.3, rxjs 6.2.2 .

To my issue:

I implemented a Service `RespSearchService` which is responsible for getting information from a Sharepoint.

Following code requests a JSON from the Sharepoint:

```
public search(queryString: string): Observable<any> {
    return from(
        web.siteUsers
            .filter("substringof(\'" + queryString + "\',Email)")
            .get()
            .then(v => {
                console.log('search', v);
            })
    );
}
```

The above code works as expected and is logging the JSON to the console.

My issue lies within another component where I subscribe to the `Observable`, as I did in all other cases, where it works. But somehow here it will not work. It seems like the Observable returns an empty object as the log to the console says `undefined`.

```
export class ClaimFormInfoComponent implements OnInit {

    public claim: Claim = new Claim();
    public results: any;
    queryField: FormControl = new FormControl();
    constructor(private data: DataService, private respSearch: RespSearchService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.data.currentClaim.subscribe(claim => this.claim = claim);

        this.respSearch.search("chri").subscribe((response: any) => {
          this.results = response;
          console.log('results', this.results); \\-> results undefined
        });
    }
}
```

I am stuck. I have no more ideas nor can I find anything useful on the internet.

Thanks in advance for any hint or idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you [return the `.then()` as a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value), of which it would be undefined because you did not return anything inside the call back.

To get rid of the undefined, you would want to return the value of V:

```
.then(v => {
    console.log('search', v);
    return v;
})
```

But then again (sorry the pun), you would just want to return the `.get()` promise. If you really want to console log the values, you can use the `tap()` operator:

```
public search(queryString: string): Observable<any> {
    return from(web.siteUsers
        .filter("substringof(\'" + queryString + "\',Email)")
        .get()
    )
        .pipe(
            tap(v => console.log('search', v))
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. I will read further about that.